# Conditional probability distribution of a Brownian particle surviving forever

Tags: pr.probability, brownian-motion

Consider the drift Brownian motion $X_t:=1+bt+W_t$, where $(W_t)_{t\ge 0}$ is a Brownian motion starting at zero. Set $\tau:=\inf\{t\ge 0: X_t=0\}$. Assume $b>0$, then $\mathbb P[\tau=\infty]>0$. What is the conditional law of $X_{\infty}$ knowing $\tau=\infty$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the law of Large numbers, $X_t/t \to b$ almost surely as $t \to +\infty$, hence $X_t \to +\infty$ almost surely as $t \to +\infty$. Therefore $X_\infty = +\infty$ almost surely under $P$ and also under $P[\cdot|\tau = \infty]$.

Comment: I see that $X_\infty = +\infty$ almost surely under $P$ — but I don’t think that implies much about $P[\cdot|\tau = \infty]$ since $\tau=\infty$ is a measure-0 condition.

Comment: @Matt F. You have $P[\tau=\infty]>0$, so there is no problem.

Comment: @ChristopheLeuridan Thanks a lot for your answer. Let $p_t$ be the conditional density function of $X_t$ knowing $\tau>t$, i.e. $\mathbb P[X_t\in dx|\tau>t]=p_t(x)dx$. What can we conclude for $\lim_{t\to\infty}p_t(x)$?

Comment: To the contrary, $P[\tau=+\infty]=0$, by the recurrence property — see eg the reference at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4460636/recurrence-of-brownian-motion-in-one-dimension

Comment: @Matt F. You forget the drift! Brownian motion with constant drift is transient.

Comment: @GJC20 The density and the distribution function of $X_t$ under $P$ and under $P[\cdot|\tau>t] $converge pointwise to 0 as $t \to +\infty$.

Comment: @GJC20 : As Christophe Leuridan noted, the conditional density of $X_t$ given $\tau>t$ will go to $0$ pointwise as $t\to\infty$. However, it is not hard to find a simple expression for the conditional density of the standardized version $Z_t:=(X_t-EX_t)/\sqrt{Var\,X_t}$ given $\tau>t$ and show that it will go to the standard normal density pointwise as $t\to\infty$.

Comment: Previous comment continues: At least intuitively, this should be clear, as $X_t$ for large $t$ will "forget" whether the process previously reached $0$ or not. So, for large $t$,  the conditional distribution of $X_t$ given $\tau>t$ will be close to the unconditional distribution of $X_t$.

Comment: @GJC20 Yes. Moreover, the distribution of $X_t$ given $X$ never reached $0$ is above (for the stochastic ordering) the distribution of $X_t$. I think that all these distributions can be computed explicitly.